# tcp connection in symbian c++ using Carbide

Tags: c++, symbian, carbide

I am new in symbian c++.

I have a assignment to write a program to "create a tcp/ip connection" in Symbian c++ using Carbide.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RSocketServ](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/reference/reference-cpp/ESock_Server/RSocketClass.html) and [RSocket](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/reference/reference-cpp/ESock_Server/RSocketClass.html). It is essentially analogous to BSD style sockets. You will need to also familiarize yourself with Symbian's asychronous APIs and Active Objects